# Is there a better way to merge items of a tuple that has a sublist without creating a new function like below?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list:

```
k_list = [(1,2,3,['a','b','c']), (4,5,6,['d','e','f']), (7,8,9,['g','h','i'])]
```

Want to merge the sublist of each tuple like:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'), (7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i')]
```

OR

```
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']]
```

I have come up with the below solution:

```
new_list =[]

def removeNesting(nest): 
    for e in nest: 
        if type(e) == list: 
            removeNesting(e) 
        else: 
            output.append(e) 
    return output

for i in k_list:
    output = []
    new_list.append(removeNesting(i))
print new_list
```

But I don't feel like its an ideal solution, so tried doing something without using a function, below code works fine when there are no integers in the list:

```
new_list1 = []
for e in k_list:
    total = []
    for i in e:
        total += i   
    new_list1.append(total)
print new_list1
```

But when there are integers in the list, I get the error at this line:   `total += i`

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

How can this be fixed?

Thank you for reading and the help in advance!!

Comment: Use the `*` unpacking operator. Try out `(1, 2, 3, *['a', 'b', 'c'])`. Also, in the future, use `isinstance(obj, list)` not `type(obj) == list`. And better yet, use `collections.abc.Sequence` and not `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(a,b,c,*d) for a,b,c,d in k_list]
[(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'), (7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i')]
```

Comment: Works great, for the above list, but what if the integer part of list is too long:
[(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,['a','b','c']), (6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15['a','b','c'])]
or integer length is a variable like:
[(1,2,3,4,5,['a','b','c']), (6,7,['a','b','c'])]

Comment: [blhsing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57682067/674039) will work for that case

Comment: blhsing answer doesn't work for me at all for the original list i posted as well, says invalid syntax at *

Comment: Works for me.  You might want to upgrade to a more recent version of Python

Answer (score 2):

You can use the generalized unpacking operator to pack the items before a sub-list into another list so that you can use the `+` operator to merge them:

```
[a + b for *a, b in k_list]
```

This returns:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that last nested item is always an iterable (independently of overall number of inner items)

```
k_list = [(1,2,3,['a','b','c']), (4,5,6,['d','e','f']), (7,8,9,['g','h','i'])]
res = [list(i[:-1]) + i[-1] for i in k_list]
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the non-list items in lists you can consistently iterate them all with a double for comprehension.
1
It's not easy to read though:

```
>>> [ 
...   tuple( 
...     [ 
...       sublist_element for subsublist_or_number in  sublist for sublist_element in ( 
...         subsublist_or_number # either a list  
...         if isinstance(subsublist_or_number, list)  
...         else [subsublist_or_number] # or a number 
...       ) 
...     ] 
...   )  
...   for sublist in k_list  
... ]                                                                                                   
[(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f'), (7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i')]
```